# Why can't I download and purchase this pre-order bundle?

Tags: xbox-one, xbox-network

I was trying to download the Dragon Ball Xenoverse pre-order content from the Xbox store, but when I click on "bundle only" it brings me to something that says "we didn't find anything".

**I really want to have the content.** So am I not able to, or can I do something?

Comment: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=xbox+one+store+%22bundle+only%22+%22couldn%27t+find+anything%22 shows other people having similar problems with other games, especially 360 games. http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691088-xbox-one/72977943 suggests you might be clicking on the wrong version

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this game was released on both Xbox 360 and Xbox One. The issue you're having seems to be related to trying to buy 360 games from the Xbox One store.

If you're intending to buy the Xbox One version, make sure you select the correct one.

If you're trying to buy the 360 version, it may work better to try buying it from the Xbox.com store and then downloading it on your console. From [a thread on the Xbox One forums](https://forums.xbox.com/xbox_support/xbox_one_support/f/5574/p/2175759/5676406.aspx):

> Not all Xbox 360 games are able to be purchased on the Xbox console. In this particular case you would need to purchase Dark Souls on an Xbox 360 console or on Xbox.com. This link HERE will take you to the purchasing page on Xbox.com. Once you purchase the game on the website, you'll be able to download the game from the Ready to Install section on the Xbox One console.
>   Let us know how it goes!

The person with the issue then came back and said that that fixed it.